# Is a iOS silent notification received when the app is killed

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

when sending a background push with `"content-available": "1"`, to an app that is killed by the user, the application is not launched into the background mode and the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is not called as the [Apple doc say](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application):

> Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app. [...]In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a remote notification arrives.
>   **However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it.**

My question is: Is there is any way to access this silent push payload the **next time the user** starts the application?

I tried using the `launchOptions` of the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method but they do not contain the push payload.

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
```

My use case is that I rely only on the push channel to receive data to the app but the app cannot *pull* them.

Comment: Relying on push is probably a bad idea, what if the user refuses permissions to push notifications? Or subsequently turns them off?

Comment: The user permissions do not affect the silent pushes. Even if the user turns off this push **notifications**, the app still can receive the silent payloads

Comment: Ah. Then I've learned something new today!

Comment: @Jan did you find anything? I am kinda in this situation right now? What strategy should I use here in this condition?

Comment: When the app is killed, there is no way to receive any remote pushes so you just have to accept that :) I think Apple is doing this "by design"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is: no, you cannot.

You also won't be able to use VoIP pushes, the only option would be to use regular pushes with a push notification service extension. Share a keychain between your app and this extension, save the push payload in the keychain when receiving a notification and retrieve it with your app when it enters foreground.
Downside is you will need to present a visual notification to the user, but it can be silent, and you can choose to present whatever text you want (the best option will depend on what your app does and what's the purpose of this notification).

Answer (score 0):

You may use a VoIP Push message, see here:

[Voice Over IP (VoIP) Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html)

> There are many advantages to using PushKit to receive VoIP pushes:
>
> - [...]
> - Your app is automatically relaunched if it’s not running when a VoIP push is received.
> - [...]

Be aware, that your app must have background mode with VoIP capability enabled, which may be an issue for app store approval if misused.

Comment: yeah I was looking onto this VoIP push as well. Isn't this reserved only for apps that actually do VoIP?

Comment: I believe I cannot use the PushKit if my app is not providing VoIP features at all, can I?

Answer (score -2):

Looking at the documentation, it seems like you should implement this method:

optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], 
   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

Within that method, write your code to store the payload (userInfo). Maybe store it in the userDefaults temporarily. Then when the application launches, check to see if the payload is available.

Comment: I did implement this method but it is not called when the application is killed. The documentation I quoted is the documentation if this method

Comment: And you've enabled the "Push Notifications" option, and selected the "Background Fetch" and "Remote Noticications" checkboxes located in the "Capabilities" tab when you select your Xcode project?

Comment: yes I did. The "normal" background silent notification works fine. I'm asking just if there is a way to get the payload at next app start in case the user kills the app