# Remove remote push notification while app closed

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, push, removable

I am developing an iOS app using Swift which has push notification feature. I've implemented push notifications feature  in my project and want to remove push notification when it's necessary (for instance message has been deleted by user A and push message is still visible on User's B screen). I used this article (https://medium.com/@sebastianosiski/implementing-removable-remote-notifications-on-ios-a17d74832bde) and it works fine while app in background mode. But when app is closed I cannot remove push notification. Is it possible to remove it while app is closed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a iOS silent notification received when the app is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526439/is-a-ios-silent-notification-received-when-the-app-is-killed)

Comment: @LouFranco Thanks a lot. It seems I cannot do this. But some messengers can do this when app is terminated.

Comment: @denickman, I think, as most messengers are also providing video possibilities, they can use the voip tag for push messages. And I think  - with voip tag, you can raise application even if it has been terminated.